# A question about finite dimensional function vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let $V$ be a nontrivial finite-dimensional subspace of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, prove that there exists $g \in V$, such that $\int^1_0g^2=1$ and $\max g^2\ge\dim V$.

Comment: that's definitely false if $V=\{0\}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I just selected a basis, tried to form a function that peaks sharply, but failed.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

(Assuming we're talking about real-valued functions:)

Say $f_1,\dots, f_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $V\subset L^2([0,1])$. Since $$\int_0^1\sum_{j=1}^n f_j^2=n$$there must exist $t\in[0,1]$ with $$\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(t)^2\ge n.$$Hence there exist scalars $a_1,\dots a_n$ with $\sum a_j^2=1$ and $$\sum a_jf_j(t)\ge\sqrt n.$$

Comment: What's the problem?